How is data loaded in BIG ENDIAN format on ARM7TDMI (ARMv4T)?
I am getting confused for how data is loaded when it is stored in BIG ENDIAN format. One of the examples I am not able to wrap my head around is:
Suppose the value 0xBABEFACE is stored to address 0x400 in a big-endian configuration, then
0x400 - BA
0x401 - BE
0x402 - FA
0x403 - CE

For the instruction LDR R3, 0x402
it loads full word starting from address 402, which is FA.
FA is being sent first, then CE, then 00 as there is no other data. Then the data loaded in R3 is 0xFACE0000 (because it starts from FA and moves up) or 0x0000FACE??
Edit- I apologise for writing half information, I have added the required information. Regarding the 3-byte instruction, you are correct the that the instruction size is not 3 but in fact 4 bytes, however, this is the example that my professor has given in the study-slides.
EDIT after the first answer was posted:
CPU architecture - ARM7 | Assume data at all memory addresses to be 0 other than the one specified

no, what you show is not the big-endian storage of 0xBABEFACE. It's the big-endian storage of 0xBEBAFACE.

you will need to tell us which assembler platform you mean, because your LDR seems to have very specific semantics, and you forgot to tell us, what architecture that instruction stems from. Where do you take the "00 as there is no other data" from? That seems very wrong; you just don't know what is there, you haven't actually defined that there's 00 there!

Are you sure you mean ARM7, like the old ARM7TDMI, not ARMv7 like recent 32-bit-only ARM chips?

Yes, the old one, ARM7TDMI

The ARM7TDMI big endian is word invariant so LDR in either mode at the same address produces the same result.  Further, unaligned accesses if you disable the fault, rotate, so the answer is not only 0xFACExxxx but it is specifically 0xFACEBABE.  Is that what you are getting?

Unaligned word loads on ARMv4 (the ISA for ARM7) use the low 2 bits of the address as a rotate count, as @old-timer mentions.  So none of your data actually come from zero bytes outside the 0x400 - 0x403 range of addresses.  If you wanted to copy the 4 bytes starting at 0x402 into a register or an aligned memory location (like C memcpy), you'd have to use something other than a single ldr.

If this is a class and the professor is writing a table like that and not indicating that is an LDRB view then the professor may not know how it works and my answer may be wrong.  End of the day if this is a class, the only correct answer is the one in the professors head, and it does not have to match reality.   College provides a shiny new tool box that you enter the real world with only find that half the tools you wont use and the others dont work how you think they work...(but you then get to learn reality).

Or at least the reality of your boss and co-workers which may also not match reality.  I think that is why they say ignorance is bliss...Because knowledge is pain...

Memory is not byte based and certainly for arm makes this even more confusing.
If you are on an ARM7TDMI and do a 32 bit write (STR) of 0xBABEFACE to address 0x400 in little endian mode.  Then if you are able to switch to big endian mode and disable the unaligned access fault and do a 32 bit read (LDR) from address 0x402 then you will get 0xFACEBABE.
Big/little does not matter for that processor you write 0xBABEFACE to 0x400 with an STR and read back in either with an LDR from address 0x402 get 0xFACEBABE. If you get 0xCEBABEFA please please let us know the arm docs are wrong then.
The whole answer is broken into parts.
First is the ARM7TDMI is armv4t based.  That architecture uses a WORD INVARIANT big endian mode which means word based (32 bit) transfers do not vary between big and little endian modes.  If you write a 32 bit value in one mode (STR) and read that value back (LDR) in the other mode you get the same value, no byte swap.
If you write (STR) a 32 bit value to memory in either mode then use LDRB to read it back in one mode you get one set of results and the other mode a byte swapped set of results compared to the first.  And this is in a very Intel vs Motorola way.
In little endian a write (STR) of 0xBABEFACE to 0x400, then read back with byte reads (LDRB) will give
0x400 0xCE
0x401 0xFA
0x402 0xBE
0x403 0xBA

And in big endian mode
STR of 0xBABEFACE to 0x400 and read back with LDRB
0x400 0xBA
0x401 0xBE
0x402 0xFA
0x403 0xCE

Very textbook Intel vs Motorola results thus far, and it all seems easy if you are creating and writing the data and reading it in the same mode.  It is when you start to look at the construction of the binary and/or you load a file or something into memory then how you parse through that that your world falls apart.
Memory is not byte based, think in this case of 32 bit wide memory, the STR in either mode results in, with this view of the byte based address offsets.
BABEFACE
 3 2 1 0 little endian byte offsets
 0 1 2 3 big endian byte offsets

I/we can go try to dig up documentation for the amba bus at the time, but one fully expects that if you wrote to memory at address of 0x400 with an STR the value 0xBABEFACE the 32 bit bus would have BABEFACE on it
31                0  bus data bit number
10111010...11001110

And it would go into a memory that way, likely a 32 bit wide memory but the Gameboy Advance had some 16 bit memories so it would have broken those up into two halves a chip vendor problem (arm is not a chip vendor) but let's just go with 32 bit memories to not get more confused.
When it comes out of memory a read of address 0x400,0x401,0x402,0x403 is going to just be a read of 0x400. For anything within the 0x400-0x403 range, ldr,ldrh,ldrb the bus has
BABEFACE

The processor does the work, not the memory controller in the vendors chip, to isolate the byte(s) of interest.
There was talk of barrel shifters in the ARM7TDMI days and the second part of the answer is perhaps the clue to the whole answer of what I expect you to see on a real ARM7TDMI. So not only do I expect the LDRB results above but the amda bus is going to have BABEFACE for all of those LDRB reads in both modes, but between the processor bus interface and deeper inside the processor before masking off the byte this is what I assume is happening. (an internal processor bus)
little endian

BABEFACE LDRB 0x400
CEBABEFA LDRB 0x401
FACEBABE LDRB 0x402
BEFACEBA LDRB 0x403

big endian

BEFACEBA LDRB 0x400
FACEBABE LDRB 0x401
CEBABEFA LDRB 0x402
BABEFACE LDRB 0x403

So this is my guess as to how it works.  The lower byte is defined to show up that way and the processor zeros out the other three bytes.

The LDRB (Load Register Byte) instruction loads a byte from the memory address calculated by <addressing_mode>, zero-extends the byte to a 32-bit word, and writes the word to register <Rd>.

So what we know that that processor is word invariant, so LDR in big or little endian mode against the same memory gives the same result, no byte swap.  For that generation of arm an unaligned LDR shows.
if address[1:0] == 0b00 then
  value = Memory[address,4]
else if address[1:0] == 0b01 then
  value = Memory[address,4] Rotate_Right 8
else if address[1:0] == 0b10 then
  value = Memory[address,4] Rotate_Right 16
else /* address[1:0] == 0b11 */
  value = Memory[address,4] Rotate_Right 24

Which leads to
either endian

BABEFACE LDR 0x400
CEBABEFA LDR 0x401
FACEBABE LDR 0x402
BEFACEBA LDR 0x403

So the result is documented as being 0xFACEBABE (if you write 0xBABEFACE to 0x400 using an STR and read back with LDR in either mode.  Even if you switch modes in between).  0xBABEFACE rotated right 16 bits is 0xFACEBABE.

It is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED whether an ARM implementation supports little-endian memory systems, big-endian memory systems, or both.

I do not expect, especially at that time to have both modes, I expect only little, but for whatever reasons they defined both.  I guess I could look at the ARM7TDMI and see what it says.  Okay I did that, I am not going to rewrite this answer I have been on this for several hours now.  The ARM7TDMI uses a 32 bit data bus helping the explanation above.  BIGEND is a strap signal not a coprocessor bit nor something you can do with an instruction as in the latter cores.  So you would need something on the chip vendor side to be able to actually do a write in little and read in big...You have to go on trust of me or docs to believe what is going on in memory, most likely.  Oh, the ARMV7TDMI is bi-endian as stated in the doc and selected using the BIGEND signal.  My memory tells me that you did not get RTL but instead a mask set, so if that is true then you are not compiling RTL and thus the optimizer is not removing a mode if you strapped BIGEND one way or the other your core has both.
The missing piece here is sort of seeing what the memory really looks like, textbook or otherwise folks want to live in this intel vs Motorola (if you are that old or prior examples to that, but the Intel vs Motorola war really defined modern computing (note ARM won that war in the end)).  You had segmented vs flat (well the illusion of flat we live in the illusion of flat today by implementing segmentation), you had the endians, mov vs move and a bunch of other silly stuff.  The 8088 and the 6800 you could really talk about an 8 bit memory with 8 bit addresses.  Today we have 8 bit addressing but our memories are at least 32 bits wide (plus parity or ECC so 33 or 40 or multiples).  A byte read as shown above the whole memory or bus width comes back and the processor selects the byte(s) it cares about.  A byte write goes out with the byte of interest not aligned at bit 0 on the bus unless its lower address bits are all zeros, and it goes out with a byte enable a 32 bit bus would have 4 byte enable bits to indicate which bytes on the bus are to be written and when it hits memory (ideally cache) a read-modify-write happens.  To only modify the enabled bytes and not modify the rest.
Binary construction demonstrates the word invariant nature of this generation of ARM.
add r6,r7,r8
.word 0x11223344
.byte 0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD

arm-none-eabi-as -march=armv4t so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  08 60 87 e0 44 33 22 11  aa bb cc dd              |.`..D3".....|
0000000c
arm-none-eabi-as -march=armv4t -EB  so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld so.o -EB -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  e0 87 60 08 11 22 33 44  aa bb cc dd              |..`.."3D....|
0000000c

Your first reaction may be, I thought you said it was word invariant, why is the word swapping?
00000000  08 60 87 e0 44 33 22 11  aa bb cc dd              
00000000  e0 87 60 08 11 22 33 44  aa bb cc dd              

It is not...It is both word invariant and the instructions also do not swap, but note in the file it has.  Why could that be?  Well the file is byte based yes?
           0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11
00000000  08 60 87 e0 44 33 22 11  aa bb cc dd              
00000000  e0 87 60 08 11 22 33 44  aa bb cc dd              

Being byte variant our byte address view is
BABEFACE
 3 2 1 0 little endian byte offsets
 0 1 2 3 big endian byte offsets

So from a word view
                         3 2 1 0 byte offset
0xe0876008 0x11223344 0xddccbbaa
                         0 1 2 3 byte offset
0xe0876008 0x11223344 0xaabbccdd

I should have done this from the start
add r6,r7,r8
.word 0x11223344
.byte 0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD
.ascii "1234"

00000000  08 60 87 e0 44 33 22 11  aa bb cc dd 31 32 33 34  
00000000  e0 87 60 08 11 22 33 44  aa bb cc dd 31 32 33 34  

                                    3 2 1 0
0xe0876008 0x11223344 0xddccbbaa 0x34333231
                                    0 1 2 3 byte offset
0xe0876008 0x11223344 0xaabbccdd 0x31323334

When you run through the string at address whatever the first item is 0x31
the number 1 in ASCII then 0x32,0x33,0x34 both big and little.
In order for that string to work.  If you do a "Hello World" print and run it on an ARM7TDMI if it does not crash on the way you get "lleHoW o" and so on.
So when we are storing 0xBABEFACE with an LDR we get this
BABEFACE
 3 2 1 0 little endian byte offsets
 0 1 2 3 big endian byte offsets

reading sequentially using LDRB from 0x400 to 0x401 little endian is 0xCE,0xFA,0xBE,0xBA and big is reversed from that.  I and maybe there is a we that thinks when you wrote
0x400 - BA
0x401 - BE
0x402 - FA
0x403 - CE

You were thinking in a strb/ldrb big endian mode or more like a Motorola (vs Intel) big endian.  To truly see this on an ARM7TDMI you would need one with both modes and be able to switch modes from code and disable the unaligned fault and then somehow see the results without the results being skewed by endianess or transfer size. (seeing the TRM unless the chip vendor provided a register to switch you are one mode or the other even though the core can do both).
Starting with the armv6 arm switched to BYTE INVARIANT big endian and the terms BE32 (WORD INVARIANT) and BE8 (BYTE INVARIANT) came along.  As the name states the cores with BE8 (none have both modes armv4 and 5 are BE32 the rest are BE8 including the cortex-ms I believe, I do not know about the aarch64 ones). (gnu does not necessarily see armv7 = armv7a I think it sees it as armv7m which can get you into trouble if not careful)(I mean full sized non-cortex-m when I use it).  This also requires the addition of saying the instructions do not vary, they do not swap.  So if you build a binary for armv7 the WORD swaps not the bytes nor instruction.
00000000  08 60 87 e0 44 33 22 11  aa bb cc dd 31 32 33 34  be8 little
00000000  08 60 87 e0 11 22 33 44  aa bb cc dd 31 32 33 34  be8 big

So byte invariant means the first byte in the file is byte 0 which is not a swap.  So we see the instruction and the bytes not change, but the word swaps.  The 32 bit instruction and 32 bit value have different orientation, indicating a BE8.  The byte based stuff has not moved indicating BE8.
An armv7a ARM ARM says this for LDR
elsif UnalignedSupport() || address<1:0> == ‘00’ then
  R[t] = data;
else // Can only apply before ARMv7
  R[t] = ROR(data, 8*UInt(address<1:0>));

Which implies unaligned access came about, in a way x86 programmers are used to, with armv7 and not before.  But that is not true, the armv6 arm11 mpcore (the first of the mpcores before the cortex-a/armv7 products) did support unaligned access it would generate the extra bus cycle or transaction as needed.  I would say there were two generations of armv6 the arm1176 and such a bunch of them with different numbers then the armv6 mpcore, not compatible with the other arm11s.  Really a stepping stone to the armv7 Cortex-As.   Perhaps for this reason but sadly arms documentation ends with armv5 with a little armv6 sprinkled in but not complete and then started over with armv7ar then started over with armv8a (aarch64), they left us armv6 folks to struggle (And learn all of this above...fill in the blank).
Point of this last bit is, not only is the ARM big endian not some purist 1980s Motorola big endian, arms big endian is not ARM's big endian, you have to look at specific architecture and transaction to even begin to talk about it. If you learned one and then look at the other you will be very confused.
Not that you did this at all and I wonder what your real question was about, I can guess but I may be wrong, but in my experience, esp with old and new arms and worse a big endian xscale (made by intel, yes not only did intel make arms they made some big endian in intel chips) when someone says endian, every one seems to freak out.  The silicon team the hardware team the software teams, everyone starts to plan for byte swapping, be it big or little endian, if someone felt the need to say endian in a document...And you end up with garbage that ultimately software has to unravel if even possible.  Do your system engineering and the word endian will for the most part go away.  Never make assumptions, read the relevant docs, assume the docs are buggy, test the docs against the real hardware/logic and go from there, tune your system engineering solution.
And this includes when you have a bi-endian processor do not assume what I call the Intel vs Motorola endians, which it seems most folks that responded did assume. (some before you specified arm).  Some folks think armv7 is also known as ARM7 which they are literally, the two end points of the 32 bit arm history, the beginning and the end.  So that is why there was a clarification on the ARM7 as ARM7 and ARMv7 have different answers to your question, but it still matters on how you put the value into memory with what instructions in what mode and how you are reading them out with what instructions in what mode.

In big endian, 0xBABEFACE would be represented in memory as 0xBA, 0xBE, 0xFA, 0xCE.
In little endian, 0xBABEFACE would be represented in memory as 0xCE, 0xFA, 0xBE, 0xBA.
You say the word is stored in memory in big endian representation. Assuming memory locations 0x404 and 0x405 contain zeros, the memory would then look like this:
0x400 - BA
0x401 - BE
0x402 - FA
0x403 - CE
0x404 - 00
0x405 - 00

The CPU reads an entire word from address 0x402. This is four bytes. The question then is, how does the CPU interpret those four bytes: most significant byte first, or least significant byte first?
Under little endian, the four bytes are interpreted least significant byte first.
Under big endian, the four bytes are interpreted most significant byte first.
So:
On a big-endian machine, the register will contain the value 0xFACE0000.
On a little-endian machine, the register will contain the value 0x0000CEFA.

Notes:
An architecture capable of handling 32-bit words is highly unlikely to be transferring bytes one-by-one between the memory and the CPU, so I would recommend to not think of it as first loading this byte, then loading that byte, etc.
When talking about CPUs, memory, etc. we do not use the word "send". We say "load", "store", "copy", "transfer", etc. but not "send".
There is no such thing as "no other data". There is always "other data". (If there really was no other data, the instruction would result in an "invalid memory access" signal and your process would be killed.) So, you generally must specify what the other data is; zeros are not automatically assumed.

Thank you for the explanation. I added the missing information. In ARM7 you can use any endianness. The answer given to this example is 0x0000FACE and I can't understand how they are concluding this

If you can use any endianness in ARM7, then you still have to specify what endianness you are using in your scenario. You have stated that the word has been stored in big endianness; fine; now, in what endianness are you trying to read it?

In any case, no matter what endianness you are trying to read as, with the parameters of the situation as described, the value read will not be 0x0000FACE, I don't care who gave that answer to this example.

there are lots of 3-byte word architectures, mostly DSPs

@phuclv thanks for the link.  I guessed that; that's why I wrote "that I know of".  But the chances that the OP had such an architecture in mind, are slim.

Outside of ARM (e.g. PDP-11), there are endianness other than big and little.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian .  But it's pretty unlikely that any real ISA would have different orders for the bytes of the first half vs. for the bytes of the second half of a 4-byte word like the OP is showing with BE BA FA CE.  Still, that is a hypothetically-possible byte-order for a 32-bit machine.  But not for ARM.

@PeterCordes I learn new things every day.  I made a correction to account for this.

the arm7 is an armv4t which whose big endian is word invariant later called BE32.  armv6 they moved to byte invariant called BE8.  Any discussion of arms and endians relies heavily on the specific transaction sizes along with mode as to where things land, we are decades away from the intel vs motorola war days with their simplified versions of big and little.

We shouldn't think of order of sending/ receiving, that is an implementation detail.
Endian-ness is a set of mathematical formulas describing the relationship between consecutive bytes in memory — rather than an ordering of what happens in time, ie, first, then second and so on.
The formulas for big endian are

value = (((mem[addr+0] << 8) + mem[addr+1] << 8) + mem[addr+2] << 8) + mem[addr+3]

-and-

mem[addr+0] = value >> 24
mem[addr+1] = value >> 16
mem[addr+2] = value >> 8
mem[addr+3] = value;

(Note that the mem in the above hold 8 bits at each address, so there is an implicit & 0xff on writes, and also, reads in the above are taken as unsigned bytes.)
These formulas describe factual relationships and are independent of temporal orderings (i.e. what happens first within the processor).
Apply these formulas to obtain your answer.
The read of 4 bytes from address 402 will be 0xface????, where ? represents an unknown byte value as the problem set up doesn't define the values at 404 or 405 (or 0xface0000 with the assumption of 0's for otherwise unspecified memory values).
The formulas for little endian describe a different relationship of values to memory bytes, and are equally independent of any temporal ordering that the processor uses when taking multiple steps to apply endian formulas.

endianess is not global the intel vs motorola day definitions are those definitions.  before and after there were other definitions.  Very much so with ARM the endian world is not as trivial as the intel vs motorola wars days.  You have to look at architecture and mode and instruction and have some sort of understanding of what is really in the memory in order to know what will come out.

Sure, but at the end of the day, we’re going to use one of these formulas or the othe.
